# REST API standard for resources under resources

Tags: rest, api, api-design

I have list of resources under endpoint /resources which contains another list of resources of type list1, list2 /resources/list1, /resources/list2 how should my endpoint look like?

/resources?search=list1type,list2type or
/resources/list1type return all different types of lists ?

Eg: I have /accounts and there are more than 1 accounts in this pool.
each account has list of orders, list of orders in shopping cart.

idea is to display everything when primary access endpoint using /accounts
and its individual account does not have access to other accounts.

what would be my endpoints in each case and how should i design my api.

Comment: can you post your code as well ?

Comment: when admin has 6 child accounts and 2 of them are blocked, /accounts will return 4 accounts in response, what HTTP response code should endpoint return? 200 OK or 206 partial content or 207 Multi-status?

Comment: if you post the part of your code, then we can see and tell you

Comment: sorry Ravi I dont have code for my question.